# Launchig an activity from list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

### I am trying to achieve Many to one mapping in ListView and populate elements relating to that item from the database

[image: Img]

- *Hello I am trying to solve a problem which involves launching an activity on click of an item*
- *I am successful on launching an activity on click of an element*

---

- I have a requirement and need some ideas on how to achieve that
- As I said onclick of an item I launch an activity as many to one
  mapping, Suppose I click an element  Item-1 the activity should
  populate the text-views in the new activity from elements related to
  that activity
- Again same if I click item-2 it should populate the text-views of in
  the same new activity with elements related to that item 2 activity
  from the database

**Many to one mapping is must I am trying to achieve**

- Any ideas on how to achieve this
- Any links to understand the concept will be helpful

  **Ps::** I am retrieving data from server as JSON resonse

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use an array adapter or base adapter to populate your list view. Syntax and concepts are well explained on the developer's website.

2) For the list, setup an OnItemClickListener and inside the function, pass an intent to the next activity. While passing the intent, use the putExtra feature to pass your item selected details to the next activity.

3) In your next activity, get the data from the previous activity and use the data to traverse the JSON response from the server. Using an Async Task will be essential at this juncture. You can get an idea about Async Task by just googling it. Many great tutorials are available.

4) When you get any data from the server, create dynamic textViews to display your data.

References:
[Developer's Website](http://www.developer.android.com)